# Running the jar file on Windows 7 and problems in displaying JTtextArea's

Tags: java, windows, intellij-idea, jtextarea

I have an intellij project that I run its jar file on my Windows 10 computer without any problems, when I bring it to my Windows 7 laptop, when I run it, it shows a small and shrunken TextArea , however, labels and buttons are fine. My attempts to change the version JRE have been unsuccessful.

Can Anybody Help?

Comment: Do you have a screenshot to show the problem? From the description, it may be related to the display scaling feature of Windows.
Also, unsuccessful attempts to change JRE mean that the problem occur on any JRE or that it's impossible to change JRE on Windows 7 somehow?

Comment: Are you using a layout manager?  If the default is removed (set to null) it might cause inconsistencies.

Comment: @JockX solved problem by change resolution after update driver